# Trouble Routing to active_storage_attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, sortablejs

implementing drag and drop for active storage attachments.  Some code from goRails and some from my brain/the web.

Since we are ordering attachments, I went ahead and created a model and controller to represent them since installing activestorage does not.

I am using "acts_as_list" so needed a model to add the acts_as_list hook.

So I have:

models/active_storage_attachment.rb

```
class ActiveStorageAttachment < ApplicationRecord
 acts_as_list
end
```

controllers/active_storage_attachments_controller.rb

```
class ActiveStorageAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_active_storage_attachment, only: [:move]

  def move
    @active_storage_attachment.insert_at(params[:position].to_i)
    head :ok
  end

  private
  
  def set_active_storage_attachment
    @active_storage_attachment = ActiveStorageAttachment.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

I also added a route:

```
  resources :active_storage_atachments do
    member do
      patch :move
    end
  end
```

The route is simple for sortablejs to call via js for an ajax request.

The call ends up being something like this:

```
https://myamazonurl.com/active_storage_attachments/96/move
```

Rails is telling me no route exists but if I run rails routes I SEE the freaking route.

```
move_active_storage_attachment_path PATCH   /active_storage_attachments/:id/move(.:format)  
active_storage_attachments#move
```

I would assume this is only the beginning of my trouble but I can't sort out why the simplest part of this, the route, is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> Since we are ordering attachments, I went ahead and created a model and controller to represent them since installing activestorage does not.

**Wrong.** ActiveStorage has a model named [`ActiveStorage::Attachment`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attachment.html). The model exists in the Rails gem - not in your application code. I wouldn't advise adding your own `ActiveStorageAttachment` model as this seems like an open invitation for bugs and confusion - especially as all the macros setup assocations to `ActiveStorage::Attachment`.

In some cases if you need to add a lot of buisness logic to your attachments you might actually be missing an intermediary model:

```
class Sortable < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :file
  acts_as_list
  delegate :service_url, # ...
    to: :file
  def move
     #...
  end
end
```

I would generally advise this over adding columns to `active_storage_attachments` and monkeypatching `ActiveStorage::Attachment`.

> I would assume this is only the beginning of my trouble but I can't sort out why the simplest part of this, the route, is not working.

My guess is that you're not using the correct HTTP method. You want to use a POST request with the `_method=PATCH` parameter or a native PATCH request. Check your logs.

I would advise an integration test (request spec in RSpec) before you do the JS integration as you want to ensure that the server side works as intended before you start approaching the problem from both ends.

Comment: Really appreciate this....I'm obviously waaay off the path.  Search as I might there is not a lot of insight into how to add sortable functionality to these attachments.  I am struggling to understand how to interact directly with the attachment model...for example to update the new "position" field that I have added.  Any idea how to interact with the ActiveStorage::Attachment model in a responsible way?

Comment: Here is my question after working through some of this.  What is best practice to add acts_as_list to the activeStorage::Atachment model without editing Gem directly?  Same goes for a new method I'd like to add to its controller.